# problem while display the data on server at time of login give error

Tags: php

Undefined index: Gender in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\stud.php on line 67

> FEMALE  Notice: Undefined index: Gender in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\stud.php on line 68
>   MALE  Notice: Undefined index: Gender in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\stud.php on line 69
>   OTHER

```
Gender:<td> 
<input type="radio" name="Gender" required value="FEMALE" <?php echo  isset($student) && $student ['Gender'] === 'FEMALE' ? 'checked' : ''?>>FEMALE
<input type="radio" name="Gender" required value="MALE" <?php echo  isset($student) && $student ['Gender'] === 'MALE' ? 'checked' : '' ?>>MALE
<input type="radio" name="Gender" required value="OTHER" <?php echo  isset($student) && $student ['Gender'] === 'OTHER' ? 'checked' : '' ?>>OTHER</td></tr>
```

Undefined index: Gender in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\stud.php on line 67

> FEMALE  Notice: Undefined index: Gender in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\stud.php on line 68
>   MALE  Notice: Undefined index: Gender in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\stud.php on line 69
>   OTHER

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Gender:<td> 
<input type="radio" name="Gender" required value="FEMALE" <?php echo  isset($student) && $student ['Gender'] === 'FEMALE' ? 'checked' : ''?>>FEMALE
<input type="radio" name="Gender" required value="MALE" <?php echo  isset($student) && $student ['Gender'] === 'MALE' ? 'checked' : '' ?>>MALE
<input type="radio" name="Gender" required value="OTHER" <?php echo  isset($student) && $student ['Gender'] === 'OTHER' ? 'checked' : '' ?>>OTHER</td></tr>

Comment: Please put it in the question. I can't read it in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

My be Gender $student does not have index 'Gender', You can do it by below-

```
Gender:<td> 
<input type="radio" name="Gender" required value="FEMALE" <?php echo  isset($student ['Gender']) && $student ['Gender'] === 'FEMALE' ? 'checked' : ''?>>FEMALE
<input type="radio" name="Gender" required value="MALE" <?php echo  isset($student ['Gender']) && $student ['Gender'] === 'MALE' ? 'checked' : '' ?>>MALE
<input type="radio" name="Gender" required value="OTHER" <?php echo  isset($student ['Gender']) && $student ['Gender'] === 'OTHER' ? 'checked' : '' ?>>OTHER</td></tr>
```